# commit renamed file to svn repository

Tags: svn, commit, subclipse

I had committed a single java source file (A.java) into a svn repository(local->remote) then later I renamed it as B.java (local). Now I see blue arrow pointing to left direction appears on the B.java in Package Explorer. Some said that blue arrow means "a versioned file that needs to be added to the remote repository. These are typically files you have either renamed or moved to a different directory.".

What should I do in order to safely commit the B.java file?

I use subclipse in eclipse helios IDE to check in/out files to/from svn repository.

Comment: How did you rename the file? Did you do a regular rename or did you do an svn rename?

Comment: I did right click on the file then Refactor > Rename.

Comment: I don't use those specific tools, but you need to do a `svn mv` (same as `svn rename`) to tell subversion that you are moving/renaming the file.

Comment: As crashmstr said, if you are doing a right click rename then that would break the file from the repository. I will update my response in the answers section.

Comment: In Eclipse, you can just refactor > rename.  Eclipse tells the framework you did this and Subclipse will convert that to a svn mv for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'd appreciate everyone's advice and inputs. What I found in my case was when I just committed renamed file B.java via Team > Commit, at the remote svn repository, I ended up getting both A.java and B.java. I removed A.java manually.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you did not do an svn rename at first.

If svn is integrated with eclipse you should have the right click subversion options. First do an revert on that file to get back the version from the repository which is A.java.

Then right click and do an svn renmae, which then rename it to B.java
Then right click to the file and do and svn commit.

This should do the trick.